# How to use Synonymap in lucene 6.2.0

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using apache Lucene 6.2.0 and I'm trying to implement a custom analyzer for searching .
This is My Analyzer Class

```
        public static class  myAnalyzer extends Analyzer
{
    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String reader) {
        final StandardTokenizer tok = new StandardTokenizer();

        TokenStream result = new StandardFilter((TokenStream) tok);
        result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(tok, result); 

}
}
```

now when i am searching the index it is giving me illegal state exception like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation: reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or subclass does not call super.reset(). Please see Javadocs of TokenStream class for more information about the correct consuming workflow.
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Tokenizer$1.read(Tokenizer.java:109)

i tried using result.close(); but it didnt solved the problem..
so what am i doing wrong ? am I using two instances of the same analyzer.
```

Any code example would be highly helpful.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? You pass the SynonymMap right into your SynonymFilter's constructor.

Comment: Thanks femtoRgon

Answer (score 2):

`createComponents` does not take a Reader argument anymore, so that method is not being called. The method that will actually be called is the one that actually overrides the one in `Analyzer`, which, in your implementation, is just a  stub that returns null.

So remove `createComponents(string, Reader)`, and put your code in `createComponents(string)` (removing the call to `Tokenizer.setReader`, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the Help